# Python 3.6: csvwriter only writes the two first strings

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, python-3.6

I am trying to webscrape soccer team-names and odds from a webpage to a csv file. My problem is that it's only writing the first two strings into a csv-file. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

When I print it it works perfectly as seen on the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0piZ.jpg) but when I extract it to a csv file it's empty

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "https://1xbet.cm/en/live/Football/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Christian/Desktop/WebScraper 0.5/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

containers = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "c-events__item_col"})
for container in containers:
    teams = [x.get_text() for x in container.findAll(
        "span", {"class": "c-events__team"}
    )]
    odds = [x.attrs.get('data-coef') for x in container.findAll(
        "a", {"class": "c-bets__bet"}
    )]

    #print(teams)
    #print(odds)
    #print()

# name of csv file
filename = "C:/Users/Christian/Desktop/WebScraper 0.5/1xbetLiveOdds.csv"

# writing to csv file
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

    # writing the fields
    csvwriter.writerow(teams)
    csvwriter.writerow(odds)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "https://1xbet.cm/en/live/Football/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Christian/Desktop/WebScraper 0.5/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

containers = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "c-events__item_col"})
teams_odds = []
for container in containers:
    teams_odds.append([x.get_text() for x in container.findAll(
        "span", {"class": "c-events__team"}
    )])
    teams_odds.append([x.attrs.get('data-coef') for x in container.findAll(
        "a", {"class": "c-bets__bet"}
    )])


# name of csv file
filename = "C:/Users/Christian/Desktop/WebScraper 0.5/1xbetLiveOdds.csv"

# writing to csv file
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

    # writing the fields
    for toe in teams_odds:
        csvwriter.writerow(toe)
```

Comment: Sorry I still have a problem with it. It still just prints the firrst two teams :/

Comment: @ChristianHandest What is the output of print(teams_odds)?

Comment: Wait, now it works for same strange reason. Thanks,  Илья Мурадьян! HERO!